# python tkinter if no button pressed run function

Tags: python, time, tkinter, sleep

I am currently working on a roulette game in tkinter. The problem is that I want the roulette automatically to run after a ceirtan time (20sec). But right now it will only run if the player inputs something inform of pressing a button and entering an amount of money. But I want the roulette to run every 20 sec even if the player didnt bet anything(so no button got pressed). But I cant seem to find out how.

pseudocode:

if no button got pressed after 20 sec:
   run roulette  #(roll roulette without player input and without his money)

Answer (score 1):

Not having any code makes answering this a bit harder. I believe what you're looking for is [after](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm#Tkinter.Widget.after-method).
This could run after a time period to check if the user has clicked to play. You should have a variable monitoring the user's clicks and reseting once the game's done.

some real code:

```
clicked = False

def force_play():
    if not clicked:
        play()

after(1000 * 20, force_play)
```

Comment: No, I know this after command. The thing Im looking for is how to store the users clicks in a variable. How can I store if the user has clicked a tkinter button in the last 20 sec in a variable?

Comment: If you were to provide a [mcve], I could help a lot more. There is an answer to your question but not having the above forces me to create an example which might not directly tie into what you're doing.